# Disconnect users from radius server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap, radius

I'm working a project where we need to disconnect users from a radius server (on windows server 2012 R2). Users logon via WPA2 authentication which is linked to Active Directory and are then allowed or disallowed from the network based on their group. (All of this works perfectly).

We're connecting to the server via LDAP-protocol (ASP.NET) and that works fine.

We've set up the Radius server session to 1 minute so it renews. Once we turn off a group in Active directory they should get disconnected within that minute cause the session will renew. But this is very inconsistent. Some people are getting kicked of and some are not.

We would like to disconnect clients with 100% reliability.

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and how you can actually disconnect users from their connection depends on the hardware (wireless controller/ap or switch) you're using.
Look into [RFC 3576](https://ietf.org/rfc/rfc3576.txt) for disconnecting through a RADIUS Packet-Of-Disconnect. Searching the documentation for "RFC 3576 support" will probably indicate whether you hardware supports it.

In your current method, it appears you have set a short RADIUS session timeout, thereby forcing frequent re-authentication. If some users remain connected beyond the timeout, you could also see if you can find out why the RADIUS session timeout is always not being honored by your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've been looking at the RFC protocol and it seems that the routers at this school don't have them.